# jquery droppable is not work properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

jquery

```
$(ui.helper).remove();
$(ui.draggable).draggable().addClass('listmenu');
```

css

```
.listmenu ul {
margin: 0 0 5px 0;
padding: 0 0 2px 0;
list-style-type: none;
width:185px;}
```

in my case `<ul><li>` is generate dynamically.when i want to redrop my element its not recognize css class.Any idea about this.redrop element has css(position:relative) so its go far away from droppable area.plz help.

Comment: helper:'clone' draggable element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right (I am not a 100%) sure you are looking for something like this: http://api.jquery.com/live/ as I guess the problem is that you apply the call the draggable-method before you create your `<li>`s (you are saying that you create them dynamically).

Other possibility would be to call the draggable() right after you created the `<li>`s.

Of any help?